# How to catch static member exception?

Tags: typescript, error-handling

I have a typescript class:

```
export class A {
    private static someServie = SomeFramework.find("myService");
}
```

Now the problem is the `SomeFramework.find()` is called when I just import the class `A` in some file, and I can not catch exceptions that are thrown by `SomeFramework`

How can I catch the exception from a static member? 
Maybe I'm just doing it wrong, please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I got your question correctly, you can define a `static` method and use `try catch` and assign your `static` property inside `try`, it will throw an exception if smth will go wrong, and call that method in the same file with class, it will do the job when you will use your class anywhere.

```
export class A {
    private static someServie;

    static initSomeFramework() {
      try {
         A.someService =  = SomeFramework.find("myService");
      }
      catch(e) {
         console.log('Error:', e);
      }
   }
}
A.initSomeFramework();
```